# How can I insert CSS code on direct child with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have CSS code like this.

```
.dl-container > .dl-submenu.dl-animate-out-2 { <<< My target

    Some code that I want to insert.

}
```

And this my Jquery code.

```
$( ***My target*** ).css("top", "500px" );
```

How Jquery insert `top:500px;` at my target CSS when I click some element on my website.

Comment: You cannot replace your css file. You can only do this for the page with jquery on any element.

Comment: You can only update inline css with $(elementSelector).css("top", "500px"); and you can't edit style on css file.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution instead of the `$(".myelement").css("top", "500px" );` could be to add a class.

```
.dl-container > .dl-submenu.dl-animate-out-2 {
   /* Base CSS */
   top: auto;
}
.dl-container > .dl-submenu.dl-animate-out-2.newClass {
   /* Some new CSS */
   top: 500px;
}
```

then

```
$(".dl-container > .dl-submenu.dl-animate-out-2").addClass('newClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of manipulating the css of the element **.stupid**.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".stupid").click(function(){
        $(".stupid").css("color", "red" );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stupid">Some stupid text</div>
```

You have to use

```
$(".myelement").css("top", "500px" );
```

If it works, accept it.

Comment: Can I replace ".dl-container > .dl-submenu.dl-animate-out-2" on
".myelement"?

Comment: I think you do not understand how jQuery works. That's ok, we are here to help. First thing to do is to find the desired element in your **html** code and add it a class called, let's say ".stupid". Then you add the jquery code to the page. You can't modify a **css** directly.

Comment: Thank you.I will try it.